# TypeError: classify() missing 1 required positional argument: 'featureset'

Tags: python, ubuntu, nltk, sentiment-analysis

here is my code where i invoke method classify():

```
def sentiment(text):
    feats = find_features(text)
    return voted_classifier.classify(feats),voted_classifier.confidence(feats)
```

Definition of find_features() method:

```
def find_features(document):
    words = word_tokenize(document)
    features = {}
    for w in word_features:
        features[w] = (w in words)

    return features
```

i get error:

```
TypeError: classify() missing 1 required positional argument: 'featureset'
```

where featuresets is:

```
featuresets_f = open("pickled_algos/featuresets.pickle", "rb")
featuresets = pickle.load(featuresets_f)
featuresets_f.close()

random.shuffle(featuresets)
print(len(featuresets))

testing_set = featuresets[8000:]
training_set = featuresets[:8000]
```

(Note : i am doing twitter sentiment analysis using Python 3.4 ,nltk on Ubuntu 14.04)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect you have not trained your classifier. Note the following error:

```
>>> from nltk import NaiveBayesClassifier  # for example
>>> NaiveBayesClassifier.classify(feats)
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: classify() missing 1 required positional argument: 'featureset'
```

You need to train it first:

```
>>> classifier = NaiveBayesClassifier.train(training_set)
```

Then you can classify features:

```
>>> classifier.classify(feats)  # feats == a dict of features
```